# Blue screen of death on a laptop, what could be the reason?

Tags: laptop, ssd, bsod

I have a MSI GS40 6QE (MS-14A1) laptop, it is already more than 6 years old and in the last 2 years blue screens of death have often appeared.

Various errors appear, but most often it is `CRITICAL PROCESS DIED`. For any error, there is no reference to any file in the memory dump file.

In some cases (this does not always happen), after a blue screen appears, the BIOS is loaded, instead of the system, and you cannot select the bootloader in it. You have to restart the laptop and only after restarting does the BIOS start again, in which the bootloader is not selected, but you can select Windows and the system will boot.

The death screen can appear once a week (when using the device every day), or several times a day, or even several times in 5 minutes - more on this below.

---

#### Component Information

The battery in the laptop was changed 2 times. The first one swelled, the second one stopped holding a charge. The current, that is, the third battery also holds a charge for about 10 minutes, so the laptop always works on mains power.

**Nothing else was replaced in the laptop**.

The total operating time of the SSD is `15 672` hours, the average temperature is `65-70` degrees.

The total operating time of the HDD is almost the same, the average temperature is `35-40` degrees

The Windows operating system is installed on the SSD.

---

#### My attempts to figure out what the problem is:

A blue screen can appear while watching a video, or while writing code or while playing a game, therefore, the list of reasons can be very wide:

It's worth starting with the fact that I enabled debugging and recording memory dumps during a critical system shutdown. I analyzed them using the `BlueScreenView` and `WhoCrashed` programs, but I couldn’t extract useful information from any of the dumps. The causes of the error were not drivers or libraries, only the error was indicated in the dump.

One way or another, I started going through all the possible options:

1. **Problems with drivers**

   3 years ago I installed a clean Windows 10 system and downloaded original drivers for all devices from [this site](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GS40-6QE-Phantom/support#driver). All drivers are original, so I don't think they are the problem.
2. **The problem is corrupted OS files or viruses**

   I did not find any viruses on the device, nor any damaged system files. Anyway, assuming that the problem might be with the operating system, I decided to completely reinstall it. However, during the reinstallation process the blue screen appeared again and interrupted the installation. The second time I managed to reinstall the system, but errors still appear, which means this is not the problem.
3. **RAM problem**

   I tried using the Windows Memory Checker (`mdsched`), the results are also positive, everything is fine.
4. **Problem in SSD/HDD**

   I checked the SSD and HDD using the `Victoria HDD` program, no bad sectors or other significant problems were found.

---

Now I'm not sure what exactly the problem is and how it can be solved. Of course, most likely the problem is with the storage media, but in general they work quite well and I wouldn’t want to replace them just like that. Although their service life has long expired.

**Additional context:**

Most often, the blue screen of death appears when I work with a laptop not at the table, but when I hold it in my hands. That being said, if it's on soft surfaces, I use it with a cooling pad. With this type of operation, a blue screen may appear several times within 10 minutes, but not always.

At the same time, if you deliberately tilt and turn the laptop over while working, nothing happens.

#### What else could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: “I have a MSI GS40 6QE (MS-14A1) laptop, it is already more than 6 years old and in the last 2 years blue screens of death have often appeared.” After reseating the RAM, I would recommend doing a fresh OS install. There are ways to do it without disturbing already installed docs and applications but I am not a Windows person. Maybe try running `sfc /scannow` to attempt to repair your system before a complete reinstall? An idea.

Comment: Find out the temperature specification for your SSD. Yours is running hot and double the temperature of the SSDs in my machines.